# webdriverjs 'hasContent' method?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am using webdriverjs for some testing and I am loving it so far. I am just running into an issue where I cant seem to run more broad tests. I am curious if there is any way to see if a page has specific content, but not have to pass it a particular css-selector?

I.e. I have a webpage with a bunch of text all over the place, and I specifically want to run a test to see if my page has the string "Hello World!" somewhere on the page. It doesnt matter where the string is, just that it is there.

If this isn't possible with webdriverjs, is there some other way to run this kind of test?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with webdriverjs. There is no hasContent method by default, but it's easy to create one on your own using the [getText()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html) method. getText() obtains the visible text of a given element and its subelements. So to get the whole text of a webpage you can just call in on the `<html>` element. Like this:

```
var selenium = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = selenium.By;  
var driver = new selenium.Builder().withCapabilities(selenium.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

function hasContent(content) {
    driver.findElement(By.tagName('html')).getText().then(function(entireVisibleText) {
        if (entireVisibleText.indexOf(content) > - 1) {
            // text found
        }
        else {
            // text not found
        }
    });
}
```